# How can I make a factory for class-scope fixtures with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a set of fixtures that all do the same thing, open up a json file and make it available to a test class.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def category_params(request):
    base_path = os.path.abspath(..)
    path = os.path.join(base_path, "data/category_params.json")
    with open(path, "r") as fp:
        category_params = json.load(f)
    return category_params
```

I repeat this set up for all of my different test categories in the test domain. It seems like something that I ought to be writing a single function for, but I am unsure as to how to use pytest to accomplish that. I believe I should be asking how to make a fixture factory, that is a pytest fixture object that makes other fixture objects.

Comment: Why can't you make a function and call it from each fixture? It will work just fine. You can also try making a fixture factory; I do not remember doing that, but it should also just work.

Comment: I would like to keep the amount of code to a minimum and making a function and calling it from each fixture adds a bit. I would like to use the fixture factory, but am unsure how to implement it.

Comment: Do you actually mean single fixture function that would load a different JSON file?

Comment: Each test class requires a different JSON file. I don't know if that would mean creating a separate fixture for each class or just calling a fixture function that loads params for that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [parametrize your fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures) function which means that each test can give it a a different JSON file to load:

```py
import pytest
import os
import json


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def json_content(request):
    base_path = os.path.abspath(..)
    path = os.path.join(base_path, request.param)

    with open(path, "r") as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)

    return data


@pytest.mark.parametrize("json_content", ["abc.json"], indirect=True)
def test_a(json_content):
    print(json_content)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("json_content", ["xyz.json"], indirect=True)
def test_b(json_content):
    print(json_content)
```

**Note:** The test examples don't show use of the same fixture per class but  that's not necessary to demonstrate the parametrization.

Answer (score 1):

**(Warning: I did not test this code.)**

I think something like this *should* work.

```py
def make_fixture_for(data_file):
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def params_fixture(request):
        base_path = os.path.abspath(..)
        path = os.path.join(base_path, data_file)
        with open(path, "r") as fp:
            return json.load(fp)
    return params_fixture

foo_params = make_fixture_for("data/foo.json")
bar_params = make_fixture_for("data/bar.json")
```

This defines fixture functions at the module's top level, where `pytest` expects them,
but does so in a sort of compact way.

This can be done in one loop over data file names and some mucking with `globals` to put them into the module's top-level context, but it would feel like impenetrable magic. The code above is very trivial.

*Maybe* `pytest` would not like a lot of fixture functions having the same name internally; then setting `.__name__` on function may help, or not; again, I did not test this code, and I don't remember the details of `pytest`'s fixture discovery process.

Comment: This is actually a neat way of factoring a fixture and avoids having to declare `@pytest.mark.parametrize` with the same file for each test method like in my example. I'd just suggest that you fix your example (`def` missing in front of `make_fixture_for`) and demonstrate the application in a test class even though it's rather obvious.